Spring is not throwing MethodArgumentNotValidException when an invalid request body is sent to the restful service
I am working on an ecommerce backend. I have this CheckoutRestController class with this reserveCartItems(@RequestBody @Valid ReserveItemsRequest reserveItemsRequest) web service. I am sending a request to /api/v1/reserve-items with invalid values for some of the fields. In Postman I see the response status code as 400 Bad Request and response body as:
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.96</h3></body></html>

In pom.xml:
<dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

In CheckoutRestController.java:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CheckoutRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CheckoutService checkoutService;
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/v1/reserve-items", produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ReserveItemsResponse> reserveCartItems(@RequestBody @Valid ReserveItemsRequest 
            reserveItemsRequest) {
        ReserveItemsResponse reserveItemsResponse = checkoutService.reserveCartItems(reserveItemsRequest);
        if(reserveItemsResponse.getReservationStatus() == ReservationStatus.Failed) {
            return new ResponseEntity<ReserveItemsResponse>(reserveItemsResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(reserveItemsResponse);
    }

}

In ReserveItemsRequest.java:
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class ReserveItemsRequest {
    
    @NotNull(message = "User ID must not be null")
    private Integer userId;
    
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "Cart items must not be null")
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;
    
    public ReserveItemsRequest() {
        
    }
        
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }
    
    public void setCartItems(List<CartItem> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ReserveItemsRequest [userId=" + userId + ", cartItems=" + cartItems + "]";
    }
    
}

In CartItem.java:
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;

public class CartItem {
    
    @NotNull(message = "Product ID must not be null")
    private Integer productId;
    
    @NotNull(message = "Quantity must not be null")
    @Positive(message = "Quantity must be positive")
    private Integer quantity;
    
    @NotNull(message = "Price per unit must not be null")
    @Positive(message = "Price must be positive")
    private BigDecimal pricePerUnit;
    
    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    
    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    
    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    
    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    
    public BigDecimal getPricePerUnit() {
        return pricePerUnit;
    }
    
    public void setPricePerUnit(BigDecimal pricePerUnit) {
        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CartItem [productId=" + productId + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", pricePerUnit=" + pricePerUnit + "]";
    }

}

It is certain that the validation is occurring but the MethodArgumentNotValidException is not thrown in console with all details about where the validation failed. And in Postman as well why do I get the repsonse in html format rather than JSON.

By default, your exception will be caught here org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#doResolveException#Handle the exception. So, as you see, default handling is just return null and do nothing. You can extend this class and add logging. My prefers is to build own ControllerAdvice

Yes, I built a global ControllerAdvice to handle the MethodArgumentNotValidException and return the field name and error message as Map<String, String> in the response body. But this leads to strict validation of the request body with more detailed error message like this: {
"cartItems[3].pricePerUnit": "Price must be positive",
"cartItems[3].productId": "Product ID must not be null"
}, and this message is only frontend developer friendly during API testing, and the frontend developer can't use it the front end app, is this ok?

As a best practice, I would recommend that you check out support for detailed information about the problem in spring and read about RFC they mention. But it depends on your contract between the backend and the frontend. For example, in my company we use a different POJO model for error responses, but it applies to all our microservices without any exclusions.
